# When using redis sentinel how do I secure the master and replica nodes with a password?

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

I was able to add `requirepass "redis-dev-pass"` to the sentinel config files to set a password for those servers. But when adding the same field to the master and replicas including a `masteauth` field sentinel thinks that all those servers are down.

```
67476:X 10 May 2019 11:31:43.109 # Sentinel ID is 
3ef0b36a3937477ace9e9d59134272e71c256c68
67476:X 10 May 2019 11:31:43.109 # +monitor master mymaster 127.0.0.1 7000 quorum 1
67476:X 10 May 2019 11:31:48.134 # +sdown master mymaster 127.0.0.17000
67476:X 10 May 2019 11:31:48.134 # +odown master mymaster 127.0.0.1 7000 #quorum 1/1
67476:X 10 May 2019 11:31:48.134 # +new-epoch 1
67476:X 10 May 2019 11:31:48.134 # +try-failover master mymaster 127.0.0.1 7000
67476:X 10 May 2019 11:31:48.135 # +vote-for-leader 3ef0b36a3937477ace9e9d59134272e71c256c68 1
67476:X 10 May 2019 11:31:48.135 # +elected-leader master mymaster 127.0.0.1 7000
67476:X 10 May 2019 11:31:48.135 # +failover-state-select-slave master mymaster 127.0.0.1 7000
67476:X 10 May 2019 11:31:48.190 # -failover-abort-no-good-slave master mymaster 127.0.0.1 7000
67476:X 10 May 2019 11:31:48.246 # Next failover delay: I will not start a failover before Fri May 10 11:37:48 2019
```

but the replicas have no trouble connecting to the master node

```
67336:S 10 May 2019 11:29:12.060 # Server initialized
67336:S 10 May 2019 11:29:12.061 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
67336:S 10 May 2019 11:29:12.061 * Before turning into a replica, using my master parameters to synthesize a cached master: I may be able to synchronize with the new master with just a partial transfer.
67336:S 10 May 2019 11:29:12.061 * Ready to accept connections
67336:S 10 May 2019 11:29:12.061 * Connecting to MASTER 127.0.0.1:7000
67336:S 10 May 2019 11:29:12.061 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
67336:S 10 May 2019 11:29:12.061 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
67336:S 10 May 2019 11:29:12.061 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
67336:S 10 May 2019 11:29:12.061 * Trying a partial resynchronization (request bb8f55d8e8336ec1b7bcc986b712b3f1c386d37b:3864).
67336:S 10 May 2019 11:29:12.062 * Full resync from master: 233bf4156083aa06321579c328fff42f5ec4e8a9:0
67336:S 10 May 2019 11:29:12.062 * Discarding previously cached master state.
67336:S 10 May 2019 11:29:12.125 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: receiving 175 bytes from master
 67336:S 10 May 2019 11:29:12.125 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Flushing old data
67336:S 10 May 2019 11:29:12.125 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Loading DB in memory
67336:S 10 May 2019 11:29:12.126 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Finished with success
```

sentinel.conf (I have 3 of them on 5000 5001 5002)

```
port 5000
sentinel deny-scripts-reconfig yes
sentinel monitor mymaster 127.0.0.1 7000 1
sentinel down-after-milliseconds mymaster 5000
requirepass "pass"
masterauth "pass"
```

and redis.conf for master

```
port 7000
bind 127.0.0.1

requirepass pass
```

similar thing for replicas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is just a different config option

```
sentinel auth-pass mymaster redis-dev-pass
```